# VBA - Breaking a cell string into individual cells while preserving character format

Tags: vba, excel, character, string-length

I have a cell with a string of different lengths. I want split them into individual cells with a length of, say, 3 characters.

A cell with `ABCCBA` should end up `ABC` `CBA` in 2 different cells.

While a cell with `ABCDABCDAB` should end up `ABC` `DAB` `CDA` `B` in 4 different cells.

In addition to that, some of the characters are *italic*, and I want to preserve the character format in the individual cells.

Is there any convenient way to do this?

---

Using `Mid()` function in both VBA or formulas works but it didn't preserve the character format.

I tried the following, but the code gives an error.

```
' Finding number of cells
Segments = WorksheetFunction.RoundUp(Len(Range("A1").Value) / 3, 0)

' Split base on character length
For n = 1 to Segments
    Cells(2, n) = Range("A1").Characters(1 + (n - 1) * 3, 3)
Next n
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up doing something like this:

```
' Finding number of cells
Segments = WorksheetFunction.RoundUp(Len(Range("A1").Value) / 3, 0)
LenCel = Len(Range("A1").Value)

' Split base on character length
For n = 1 To Segments
    Range("A1").Copy
    Cells(2, n).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAllUsingSourceTheme
    Cells(2, n).Characters(1, (n - 1) * 3).Delete
    Cells(2, n).Characters(3 + 1, LenCel).Delete
Next n
```

I used `.PasteSpecial` to main the character format and then `.Delete` the characters. Not elegant, but does the job.

Answer (score 0):

Does this work for you.

```
 Public Sub FormatGroupings()

    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim inputString As String
    Dim Segments As Long
    Dim formatCollection As New Collection
    Dim charNum As Long
    Dim Group As Long

    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set ws = wb.WorkSheets("Sheet1")
    inputString = ws.Range("A1")

    Segments = WorksheetFunction.RoundUp(Len(inputString) / 3, 0)

    With ws

        For charNum = 1 To Len(inputString)

            If .Range("A1").Characters(Start:=charNum, Length:=1).Font.FontStyle = "Italic" Then
                formatCollection.Add "Italic"
            Else
                formatCollection.Add "Regular"
            End If
        Next charNum

        Dim counter As Long
        counter = 1

        For Group = 1 To Segments

            .Cells(2, Group) = Mid$(inputString, 1 + (Group - 1) * 3, 3)

            For charNum = 1 To Len(.Cells(2, Group))

                .Cells(2, Group).Characters(Start:=charNum, Length:=1).Font.FontStyle = formatCollection(counter)
                counter = counter + 1
            Next charNum

        Next Group

    End With

End Sub
```

Or using an Array which is possibly faster:

```
 Public Sub FormatGroupings2()

    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim inputString As String
    Dim Segments As Long
    Dim formatArr()
    Dim charNum As Long
    Dim Group As Long

    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set ws = wb.WorkSheets("Sheet1")
    inputString = ws.Range("A1")

    ReDim formatArr(Len(inputString))

    Segments = WorksheetFunction.RoundUp(Len(inputString) / 3, 0)

    With ws

        For charNum = 1 To Len(inputString)

            If .Range("A1").Characters(Start:=charNum, Length:=1).Font.FontStyle = "Italic" Then
                formatArr(charNum - 1) = "Italic"
            Else
                 formatArr(charNum - 1) = "Regular"
            End If
        Next

        Dim counter As Long
        counter = 0

        For Group = 1 To Segments

            .Cells(2, Group) = Mid$(inputString, 1 + (Group - 1) * 3, 3)

            For charNum = 1 To Len(.Cells(2, Group))

                .Cells(2, Group).Characters(Start:=charNum, Length:=1).Font.FontStyle = formatArr(counter)
                counter = counter + 1
            Next charNum

        Next Group

    End With

End Sub
```